# Retrieving MsAccess Data to ComboBox in VC++ form Application

Tags: visual-c++, ms-access, combobox

Hi i am trying to retrieve data from Ms Access database in `VC++`. As i am a new to `VC++`, please help me.

Here is the code i have written so far.

```
System::Data::DataSet^ ds=gcnew System::Data::DataSet();

        OleDbConnection ^ con=gcnew OleDbConnection("Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=dbmc.accdb; Persist Security Info=True");
        OleDbCommand^ com =gcnew OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataReader^ myReader;
        com->CommandText ="SELECT name FROM Table1";
        com->Connection = con;
        con->Open();
        try
        {
            myReader=com->ExecuteReader();
            while(myReader->Read())
            {
                String^ vName = myReader->GetString('name');
                comboBox1->Items->Add(vName);
                myReader->Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception^ex)
        {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
```

When I run this program i get an error `"Index Out of Bound"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetString()` method takes an integer of the column number as a parameter, not the column name (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) for full documentation).

Change the line

`String^ vName = myReader->GetString('name');`

to

`String^ vName = myReader->GetString(0);`